# How to give Password as an input while executing linux command 'su' command from java?

Tags: java

I am trying to execute few shell command lines from java. But it seems like am not able to switch user. I need to give password as an input while switching user.

```
        Runtime rtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process child = rtime.exec("/bin/sh \n");
        BufferedWriter outCommand = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(child.getOutputStream()));
        outCommand.write("su - username");
        System.out.println("user switched");
        outCommand.flush();
        outCommand.write("password");
        System.out.println("password entered");
        outCommand.flush();
        outCommand.write("rm -rf test.txt");
        System.out.println("file removed");
        outCommand.flush();
        outCommand.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

`write` just writes the characters you give it. It doesn't do a newline after them, so the shell just sees `su - usernamepasswordrm -rf -test.txt` from that code.

`BufferedWriter` has a [`newLine` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine--) for writing a newline sequence for the environment (e.g., using the `line.separator` property).

E.g.:

```
outCommand.write("su - username");
outCommand.newLine();                    // ***
outCommand.flush();                      // (I'd also probably put this before the output)
System.out.println("user switched");
outCommand.write("password");
outCommand.newLine();                    // ***
outCommand.flush();
System.out.println("password entered");
// ...
```

---

Side note: If this code is going to be used anywhere other than your machine, I suggest doing some reading on best practices around passwords. In particular, the general recommendation is not to store a password, even temporarily, in a `String`. Instead, use a `char[]` and keep the password in it for as little time as possible, overwriting it with other characters as soon as you can. This keeps passwords from sitting around in plaintext in memory for any significant time.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I tried like this code. But still unable to acheive. BufferedWriter outCommand = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(child.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(child
                .getInputStream()));
        outCommand.write("su - username");

        strSqlLdrOut = bufferedreader.readLine();
        buffer.append(strSqlLdrOut);
  buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
  System.out.println(buffer);    outCommand.write("Password");
  outCommand.flush();

Comment: @diwa: See the answer. You need to use `newLine` after outputting a command. You don't do that anywhere in that code.

Comment: Still the user is not getting switched. is there a way to debug?

Comment: @diwa: Yes. You use a debugger. There's one built into your IDE. You probably also want to read the child process's output and error output (so, for instance, you can see what errors it's giving you).